# Magento minimum order quantity api

Tags: php, api, magento, soap, magento-1.4

I want to set the minimum order quantity in a Magento 1.4 Shop via the SOAP V1 API.
I use this call:

```
$proxy->call($session, 'product_stock.update', 
 array($product_id, array('min_sale_qty' => 10,
 'use_config_min_sale_qty' => 0), 'default'));
```

But it doesn't work, the minimum order quantity is unchanged. It works fine when I set it in the backend. Also other API calls like product.update work fine.

Comment: Have you checked your system and server logs for any exceptions? What does the SOAP call return?

Answer (score 2):

I've only had a quick look at this, but it looks like the ability to change the `min_sale_qty` attribute using the stock item API was [only introduced in Magento 1.9](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item/Api.php#L119-L121).

Unfortunately it looks like in Magento 1.4 you [have only the following options to update](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.4/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item/Api.php#L95-L109):

- `qty`
- `is_in_stock`
- `manage_stock`
- `use_config_manage_stock`

Of course if you want to you can rewrite and extend this class and add in the functionality from Magento 1.9, which *would* allow you to update the `min_sale_qty` using the SOAP API, but not with the core code on its own (in 1.4).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, I will take a look and see if I can add the min_sale_qty in the extended class